# Generated Soap Classes for Android

Tags: android, xml, soap, generator

Currently I am working on an iPhone app. But the company also would like to have an android version for this app. 
I have programmed all the request by Soap and used for the iPhone the Soap Request Generator of Sudz-C.
I am wondering now if something similar exists for the Android, It would be nice if I don't have to program this all by myself. 
Anyone have some experiences or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I go through a lot of solution solution in WSDL 2 android. google don't matter about SOAP service and provide anything for it. wsdl2java won't work in most of case, some library cannot be use by android SDK. I suggest you to use http://easywsdl.com.

you'll see you can edit your own package name, class prefix and many other parameters depends on your need. If you have complex data and your are familiar to use Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to send parameter between your activities don't check "Use JodaDate" that is a great library for using date, but Gson doesn't support it (yet).

If you have few services that don't work (yes that can happen, depend of your WSDL configuration file), report it to contact and they will make the possible to fix your issue like they did for me.

The generator is fast. you will receive all your generated code and the .jar that you'll have to import into your project.

Answer (score 0):

ksoap2-android is what you are looking for, it will send/recive soap request's, is easy to use and on MIT license